# Center widget behavior relating to constraints

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, widget

Based on the [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html),

> ... This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are
> constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null. If a dimension
> is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is null then the
> widget will match its child's size in that dimension. ...

---

1. 

**Dummy code:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          //height: 100,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text('Logo'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:** It simply prints "Logo" that is centered horizontally BUT not vertically.

This obeys the docs, "If a dimension is unconstrained ... match its child's size". In this case, `Column` has unbounded vertical constrains thus `Center`'s incoming constraints are also unbounded. Thus Center matches height of `Text` widget and isn't centered vertically.

---

2. 

**Dummy code(with comment uncommented):**
We run the exact same code but with the `//height: 100,` being uncommented.

**What I thought should happen**: Since now vertical dimension is constrained, I thought "Logo" would be both vertically and horizontally centered.

**Actual output**: Same output as previous dummy code.

**Question**: Why does this happen? According to the docs: "widget will be as big as possible ... are null" so shouldn't the `Center` widget be big as possible and center the child vertically and horizontally.

---

Sidenote: I only get the expected behavior of being centered horizontally and vertically if I remove the `Column` widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that `Column`'s `mainAxis` which is the height is unbounded, therefore making `Center` match its child's height. Although you've constrained the `Column`'s `height` to 100, its `mainAxis` is still unbounded. Think of `Column` like a `ListView`, although the `ListView`'s height is bounded, it still allows its children to take more space than the available height.

Solutions:

1. You could center your text widget by setting `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.center`
2. Use Spacer()

Eg:

```
children: [
   Spacer(),
   Text(),
   Spacer(),
]
```

Comment: Hmm, but the docs say`This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null`. So are you implying that `mainAxis` is the dimension and not `height` because only then would the docs make sense? If that's the case, shouldn't bounding `mainAxis` by `mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max` fix it too?

Comment: @Leon bounding mainAxisSize will not fix it. Take a look at this part of the docs: `When a Column lays out its non-flex children (those that have neither Expanded or Flexible around them), it gives them unbounded constraints so that they can determine their own dimensions (passing unbounded constraints usually signals to the child that it should shrink-wrap its contents). The solution in this case is typically to just wrap the inner column in an Expanded to indicate that it should take the remaining space of the outer column, rather than being allowed to take any amount of room it desires.`

Comment: Ahh, this does make sense. But when they mention `constraints`, don't they mean the `height`(in context of `Column`) which I did bound to 100. I can't seem to find anything that talks about `mainAxis` being unbounded and causing error.

Comment: What you're doing is just bounding the Column's height and not how it lays out its children. The most important thing is the child's parent's height which is unbounded in this scenario. The best solution is to set mainAxisAlignment.

Comment: I see, 1 last query: when you say `child's parent's height is unbounded`, you're referring to the `Center` widget's height being unbounded right?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant.